# How can i get random colors for each object in canvas with JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to get random colors for each object in canvas how can i do that, I have tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var raza = (Math.random() - 0.001) * 30;
    var x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - raza * 2) + raza;
    var y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - raza * 2) + raza;
    var dx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4; //calcul viteza X
    var dy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4; //calcul viteza Y
    var color = c.strokeStyle = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(12);
    cercArray.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, raza, color));
}
```

Comment: currently i generate random circles with random speed size and color, but all circles have same color, it changes only on page refresh

Comment: Try separating your color assignments in different lines. Like c.strokeStyle = "#" + (..); var color = c.strokeStyle;

Comment: that didn't help, but thanks

Comment: A nice idea would be using hsl colors and set the hue randomly: `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`. However this has the inconvenient that you'll get allways the same saturation and lightness. Another idea would be using an array of colors and pick one color randomly `color = colors[~~(Math.random() * colors.length)];`

Comment: Also you can try to use rgb colors `rgb(${Math.random() * 255},${Math.random() * 255},${Math.random() * 255})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different ways to do this, here is an example using HSL.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let lastDate = Date.now() - 500;

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  const color = {
    h: Math.floor(Math.random() * 360),
    s: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    v: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  };

  if (lastDate + 500 < Date.now()) {
    lastDate = Date.now();
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${color.h},${color.s}% ,${color.v}%)`;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```